# Is it possible to specify that a HTTP connection should only be made over the cellular network and not over Wifi?

Tags: ios

I know its possible to detect if the connection is cellular or Wifi, but is there anyway of specifying/forcing that a http connection must go over the cellular network?

Comment: Reachability is your friend...

Comment: Thankyou, I am aware of reachability - obliquely implied by saying: "I know its possible to detect if the connection is cellular or Wifi". I am wondering if there is any direct API for forcing/specifying a connection type. Rather than monitor what the connection availability is. I want to make a HTTP connection and that must go over the cellular network.

Comment: Did you ever find a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that is a level of abstraction that the developer is not supposed to worry about.